# REST Jackson JsonDeserialize, StackOverflowError after upgrade

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, deserialization

In the previous version of jackson (1.9.2) the following code worked fine:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonDeserializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationContext;
...
@JsonDeserialize(using = RoleDeserializer.class)
public interface RoleDto {}

public class RoleDeserializer extends SomeSharedDeserializer<RoleDto> {}

public class SomeSharedDeserializer<T> extends JsonDeserializer<T> {
    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException
    {
        return jp.readValueAs(getImplementation());
    }

    public Class<? extends T> getImplementation(){ ... returns some generated implementation of RoleDto }
}
```

After we migrated to the last jackson version (1.9.13 provided by Wildfly 8.2) we got an exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct
>   instance of RoleDto, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped
>   to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with
>   additional type information

Ok, as in jackson new packages are used, we upgraded them to:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer;
```

The deserializer is visible now (the previous exception is gone), 
However, we get StackOverflowError exception. The  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper reads value (line 3023):

```
    DeserializationContext ctxt = createDeserializationContext(jp, cfg);
    JsonDeserializer<Object> deser = _findRootDeserializer(ctxt, valueType);
    // ok, let's get the value
    if (cfg.useRootWrapping()) {
        result = _unwrapAndDeserialize(jp, ctxt, cfg, valueType, deser);
    } else {
        result = deser.deserialize(jp, ctxt);
    }
```

We go to the line: `result = deser.deserialize(jp, ctxt);`

It causes to infinite loop and StackOverflowError as a result.

One of the way which is recommended is to implement our own SomeSharedDeserializer as:

```
ObjectCodec oc = jp.getCodec();
JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jp);
//here manually create new object and return it
```

But our classes are generated. As another solution I tried to use

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(jp, getImplementation());
```

But got the same result - StackOverflow exception.

How can we fix it? Can we use some deserializer, to pass it JsonParser instance, generated class that implements base interface and without StackOverflowError?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/686) is you can find a full description and trials to find a solution.
The following solution has been found:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanDescription;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.DeserializerFactoryConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ResolvableDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.SimpleType;
...
    public abstract class RestDtoDeserializer<T> extends JsonDeserializer<T>
    {
        @Override
        public T deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException
        {
            DeserializationConfig config = ctxt.getConfig();
            SimpleType simpleType = SimpleType.construct(getImplementationClass());
            BeanDescription beanDesc = config.introspect(simpleType);
            BeanDeserializerFactory instance = new BeanDeserializerFactory(new DeserializerFactoryConfig());
            JsonDeserializer deserializer = instance.buildBeanDeserializer(ctxt, simpleType, beanDesc);
            ((ResolvableDeserializer)deserializer).resolve(ctxt);
            return (T) deserializer.deserialize(jp, ctxt);
        }

        public abstract Class<? extends T> getImplementationClass();
```